# How to get predicted class label from predicted probabilities in one step?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Currently, I am using the given code bellow to calculated the probabilities score and predicted class labels.

```
y_score = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=10 ,method='predict_proba')
y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=10 )
```

But it a computationally costly method, because have to run entire model twice, is there any method that I can get both in one step.  Or how can I translate probabilities into class labels?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the probabilities, use `np.argmax()` if it's a one-hot encoded target array. It will return where the highest probability is (the prediction), e.g., row 1, 2, or 3.

Use `np.round()` if you have two classes in a 1D array, so you get predicted values of categories 0 and 1. You may have to convert to `int` for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and what if in the case of multi-class, two-class shares the same probability value.

Comment: For multi-class, you can round. There will be a `1` for the classe(s) it belongs to: `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]`, etc. If you want the class numbers: `np.where(pred == 1, axis=0)`, it will return `[3, 5, 6]`. Or maybe `axis=1` I'm not sure.